# C# Options to best consume C++ DLLs with 1000's of functions

Tags: c#, c++, dll, pinvoke, wrapper

I have around 5 C++ DLLs which have thousands of functions and so on. So the thing is, I kind of fell in love with WPF which is in C#(as I understand). But this is another language, so after doing a bit of research I found out that I could create a wrapper, and so I did(The wrapper was created in C++/CLI). The wrapper has some few conversions, and it worked fine. I also heard about Pinvoke, but my problem with all of these is that what if I don't have time to convert thousands of functions and variables? What do i then do? Is there some kind of fast way?

PS. Im using Visual Studio 2012

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to check out [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/CSharp.html).

> SWIG is a software development tool that connects programs written in
>   C and C++ with a variety of high-level programming languages.

Comment: But each time i modify my dll's, do i need to do something in SWIG again?

Comment: I haven't used SWIG personally. We needed to use some unmanaged C++ code in our C# code, and it came up when we were looking for options. We did write our own wrapper using P/Invoke. And as long as the function signatures are the same, it should work. But I'm not sure about SWIG, it is just a fast automated way to create the wrapper, even if you do need to change things every time you change something in the DLLs, it shouldn't be much of a problem.

Comment: @MiguelP Every time you build your C++ Dll have a step in your make file to generate the SWG wrapper.